# Size of the maximal function $f^*$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

How do we get the last inequality, $c_1\frac{|E|}{|x|^n} \le \chi^*_E(x) \le c_2\frac{|E|}{|x|^n} \text{ for large } |x|$? Why do we need $|x|$ to be large?

> Let $x\in \mathbb R^n$. For any measurable $E$, $$\chi^*_E(x) = \sup\left\{\frac{|E\cap Q|}{|Q|}: Q \text{ has center } x\right\}.$$
>
> If $E$ is bounded and $Q^x$ denotes the smallest cube with center $x$ containing $E$, then $$\frac{|E\cap Q^x|}{|Q^x|} = \frac{|E|}{|Q^x|}.$$
>
> It follows that there are positive constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that  $$c_1\frac{|E|}{|x|^n} \le \chi^*_E(x) \le c_2\frac{|E|}{|x|^n} \text{ for large } |x|.$$

Comment: Are you asking how to get the upper bound on the maximal function? If so, how did you get the lower bound?

Comment: @ZachBoyd I'd like to know how to get both the upper bound and the lower bound. Why do we care about this inequality? And why do we need $|x|$ to be large? What if $|x|$ is small?

Comment: An expert at harmonic analysis would probably do a better job of answering the question of why we care, but it is probably something like this: In the differentiability theory of measurable functions, one naturally gets bounds in terms of the maximal functions when proving various lemmas. So it would be good to have some idea of how big the maximal functions are.  Understanding their size in the simple (yet, in some ways, typical) case of maximal functions is a good first step. This inequality says that for large x, the maximal function always decays at a certain rate.

Comment: As for getting the inequalities, in the case where E is bounded, the large x condition allows Q to contain the entire set, so that Q intersect E is just E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use the notation $Q_{r}$ to denote the cube centered at $x$ and
side-length $r$. If $r_{x}$ is the side-length of the smallest cube centered
at $x$ and containing $E$, then for every $r>r_{x}$ we have that$$
\frac{|Q_{r}\cap E|}{|Q_{r}|}=\frac{|E|}{|Q_{r}|}=\frac{|E|}{r^{n}}\leq
\frac{|E|}{r_{x}^{n}}=\frac{|E|}{|Q_{r_{x}}|}=\frac{|Q_{r_{x}}\cap
E|}{|Q_{r_{x}}|}.
$$
This shows that all cubes centered at $x$ and side-lenght $r>r_{x}$ are not
good competitors for the supremum, that is,$$
\chi_{E}^{\ast}(x)=\sup\left\{  \frac{|Q_{r}\cap E|}{|Q_{r}|}:\,Q_{r}\text{
has center at }x\text{ and side-length }r\leq r_{x}\right\}  .
$$
Now let $B(0,R)$ be the smallest ball centered at the origin and containing
$E$. Given $|x|>2R$, find $k\geq2$ such that $kR\leq|x|<(k+1)R$. If
$$r<\frac{|x|}{4\sqrt{n}}\leq\frac{(k+1)R}{4\sqrt{n}}\leq\frac{2kR}{4\sqrt{n}
}=\frac{kR}{2\sqrt{n}},$$ then for every $y\in Q_{r}$ we have that
$|y-x|\leq\sqrt{n}r$ and so $|y|\geq|x|-|y-x|\geq kR-\sqrt{n}r>kR-\frac{kR}%
{2}=\frac{kR}{2}\geq R$, which means that $Q_{r}$ does not intersect $B(0,R)$
and, in turn, it does not intersect $E$. Thus, when $kR\leq|x|<(k+1)R$, we can
restrict our attention to cubes of side-length $r\geq\frac{|x|}{4\sqrt{n}}$.
In turn, $\frac{1}{r^{n}}\leq\frac{(4\sqrt{n})^{n}}{|x|^{n}}$ and so$$
\frac{|Q_{r}\cap E|}{|Q_{r}|}\leq\frac{|E|}{|Q_{r}|}=\frac{|E|}{r^{n}}%
\leq\frac{(4\sqrt{n})^{n}}{|x|^{n}},
$$
which shows that $\chi_{E}^{\ast}(x)\leq\frac{(4\sqrt{n})^{n}}{|x|^{n}}$.

On the other hand, if $r\geq4|x|$, then for every $y\in E$, $|y_{i}-x_{i}%
|\leq|y_{i}|+|x_{i}|\leq R+|x|<\frac{1}{2}|x|+|x|\leq2|x|\leq\frac{r}{2}$,
which shows that $E$ is contained in $Q_{r}$ and so$$
\frac{|Q_{r}\cap E|}{|Q_{r}|}=\frac{|E|}{|Q_{r}|}=\frac{|E|}{r^{n}}%
$$
and $r_{x}\leq4|x|$. Hence,
$$
\chi_{E}^{\ast}(x)=\sup\left\{  \frac{|Q_{r}\cap E|}{|Q_{r}|}:\,Q_{r}\text{
has center at }x\text{ and side-length }\frac{|x|}{4\sqrt{n}}\leq
r\leq4|x|\right\}  .
$$
Now for any such $\frac{|x|}{4\sqrt{n}}\leq r\leq4|x|$, that is $\frac
{1}{(4|x|)^{n}}\leq\frac{1}{r^{n}}\leq\frac{(4\sqrt{n})^{n}}{|x|^{n}}$, and so$$
\frac{|Q_{r}\cap E|}{|Q_{r}|}=\frac{|Q_{r}\cap E|}{r^{n}}\geq\frac{|Q_{r}\cap
E|}{(4|x|)^{n}}.
$$
In turn,
\begin{align*}
\chi_{E}^{\ast}(x)  & \geq\frac{1}{(4|x|)^{n}}\sup\bigg\{  |Q_{r}\cap
E|:\,Q_{r}\text{ has center at }x\\&\text{ and side-length }\frac{|x|}{4\sqrt{n}
}\leq r\leq4|x|\bigg\}  
=\frac{1}{(4|x|)^{n}}|Q_{r_{x}}\cap E|=\frac{1}{(4|x|)^{n}}|E|.
\end{align*}
As for why do we care,  Zach Boyd already gave a perfectly good answer. In particular the inequality from below shows that the maximal function is not integrable even if $\chi_E$ is.